# Delete Inner Text - XPath

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

Looked around but couldn't find an answer to this:

I have a XML template that I use to quickly put together a document by replacing variables in the template. However, when a value is empty I want the template's tag to return to a single tag that represents both the open/close.

For Example:

```
 <root>
  <child1>@@Variable@@</child1>
 </root>
```

So if I do a replace on this with:

```
 xml.selectsinglenode("/root/child1").innerText = Nothing
```

or

```
 xml.selectsinglenode("/root/child1").innerText = ""
```

I end up with

```
 <root>
  <child1>
  </child>
 </root>
```

Instead of my desired output of:

```
 <root>
  <child1/>
 </root>
```

I'm almost sure I'm missing something simple but I've been at this that I can't seem to figure what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `SelectSingleNode` method result to `XmlElement` and set `IsEmpty` property to true:

```
DirectCast(xml.SelectSingleNode("/root/child1"), XmlElement).IsEmpty = true;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for the example. I'm not trying to do this directly on a cloned XMLNode, but it doesn't work. Do you know if the process is different for clone's?